# Custom shopify checkout

Tags: javascript, shopify, checkout, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm facing an annoying problem about building a checkout function to shopify product. Assume that user is viewing products by ads at a random relate site like news, blog, etc…, then how can make he/she able to click the button buy and do checkout directly in this site if the product come from shopify. Take several days and It still stuck. Can I do it?  Can It be excuted in an shopify-app?

Anyone can help? Thanks!!

Tried to go through docs, create an shopify app, play around with sopify REST api

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop a Shopify Buy Button on ANY website, and then the buy button takes care of ensuring the checkout happens properly with the Shopify store selling the product. Very easy and effective to setup, and lets you sell anything on ANY other kind of website as you point out, new, blogs, ads, etc.

Comment: Thanks sir! It's crazy to know that. I don't have any experience with Shopify and being suffer with this for some days. How can I drop a Shopify Buy Button on my website? Is there any document or sth?